# Reading remote JSON object in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

While learning Chrome Extension development I attempted to load some JSON from a localhost server, so to display it within a popup.

The JSON seems to be passing through as I can display it in the console, but then it kind of 'disappears'..  I can't really make sense of what's happening, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my script **popup.js**:

```
function getLatestContents() {

    var URL = "http://localhost:8000/api/search/"
    var items = [];

    $.getJSON( URL, function( data ) {

        $.each(data, function(idx, val) {
            var link = "<a href='" + val.url + "'>" + val.name + "</a>"; 
            var element = "<li id='" + val.id + "'>" + link + "</li>" 
            items.push(element);
        });

    });

    console.log(items); // prints an array of strings 
    console.log(items.length); // returns 0 (weird)
    return items;  
}



$(function(){
    var contents = getLatestContents();
    console.log(contents);  // prints an array of strings
    console.log(contents.length);  // returns 0 (??)

    if (contents instanceof Array) {
        console.log("YES");  // returns YES
        console.log(contents.length);  // returns 0 (??)

        for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);  // nothing happens
        }

    }

});
```

As you can see I tried printing stuff out in the console to figure what's going on - however the data seem to be inconsistent with each other. The array gets printed, but its length appears to be '0'...

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Testing app",
  "description": "This extension is just a test.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "19x19.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "http://localhost/*"
   ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a test</title>
     <script src="libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="popup.js"></script>
 </head> 
  <body>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code to handle the items array needs to be inside the getJSON handler. The function getLatestContents is probably returning an empty array depending on how quickly your server responds.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Ah pointed out by Steve o'Connor above: the problem is that the JSON-handling code was positioned outside the AJAX requesting code - hence the former was erroneously executed before the latter.

This worked:

```
$(function(){
    var contents = getLatestContents();
});    


function getLatestContents() {

    var URL = "http://localhost:8000/api/search/"


    $.getJSON( URL, function( data ) {  
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(idx, val) {
            var link = "<a href='" + val.url + "'>" + val.name + "</a>"; 
            var element = "<li id='" + val.id + "'>" + link + "</li>" 
            items.push(element);
        });

        $.each(items, function(idx, obj) {
            $("#content").append(obj);
        });

    });

}
```